# On-shell SUSY-transformations for interacting Wess-Zumino model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, supersymmetry

I'm learning SUSY with [Quevedo, Cambridge Lectures on Supersymmetry and Extra Dimensions](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1491).

**Setup:**

The SUSY transformations of the component fields of a chiral field $\Phi$ are given by (p.41)

\begin{align*}
\delta_{\epsilon,\overline{\epsilon}}\varphi &= \sqrt{2}\epsilon^{\alpha}\psi_{\alpha}, \\
\delta_{\epsilon,\overline{\epsilon}}\psi_{\alpha} &= i\sqrt{2}\sigma^{\mu}_{\alpha\dot{\alpha}}\overline{\epsilon}^{\dot{\alpha}}\partial_{\mu}\varphi + \sqrt{2}\epsilon_{\alpha}F,\\
\delta_{\epsilon,\overline{\epsilon}} F &=i\sqrt{2}\overline{\epsilon}_\dot{\alpha}(\overline{\sigma}^{\mu})^{\dot{\alpha}\alpha}\partial_{\mu}\psi_{\alpha},
\end{align*}
where $\varphi$ is a complex scalar, $\psi_{\alpha}$ is a left-handed Weyl spinor and $F$ is an auxiliary field.

**My questions:**

1. Let us choose the superpotential $W(\Phi)\equiv \frac{m}{2}\Phi^2 + \frac{g}{3}\Phi^3$ together with kinetic part $\Phi^{\dagger}\Phi$ and *remove the auxiliary field $F$* via its algebraic equations of motion. *Then*, the transformation rules must change as well, correct?
2. We can use the equations of motion of the auxiliary field $F$ to remove it from the Lagrangian. How do we account for this in the transformation rules of the component fields? The transformation rules do not know anything about the model (free/interacting/massless) we are considering, so it is us who should implement this choice into the transformation rules -- but how do we do this without messing up SUSY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. When we eliminate/integrate out the auxiliary field $F$, the SUSY transformation for $F$ is rendered moot, and the appearance of $F$ on the RHSs of the other SUSY transformations is replaced with its algebraic EOM.
2. It's not true that we do not know anything about the model -- we assume that the action $S$ is SUSY-invariant. In particular, the EOM for $F$ is derived from the action.